# Pass var using onClick with function name of JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to pass 2 variable using onClick inside of `<a>` tag

Here's my code:

```
 <a onClick="pbDiv(id=1);">Enter</a>

 <script>

 function pbDiv(id){
 alert(id);
 }

 </script>
```

This works perfectly as it should be.

But the problem is I need to pass 2 variable

Example of variable

`id=1`

`name=myname`

inside of `onClick`

Is that even possible?

tried this one `onClick="pbDiv(id=1,name=name);"`

seems not working to me.

Comment: Don't pass the argument name, just pass the argument *value*. `pbDiv(1, 'foo')` But even better, avoid inline listeners entirely

Comment: how can I define them inside of function?

Comment: By defining arguments for the function (like you already are for `id`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, you define the name as an argument, and never pass in the name of the argument as a parameter. TypeScript (a version of javascript) does this, however.

```js
 function pbDiv(id, name){
   alert("id: " + id + ", name: " + name);
 }
```

```html
 <a onclick="pbDiv(1, 'foo');" href="#">Enter</a>
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined
    at HTMLTableRowElement.onclick (3:1) 

im getting this error when I tried to put the onclick on table tr

Comment: Did you forget the single quotation marks around `foo`? So that the parameter becomes a string instead of a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Pass object instead

```
<a onClick="pbDiv(options={id:1, name: 'deepak'});">Enter</a>
<script>
  function pbDiv(options) {
    alert(options.id + options.name);
  }
</script>
```